# JS загрузить данный полученные от сервера в select

Tags: javascript, html, база-данных

В html страничке есть:

```
  <select id="mySelectId" name="mySelect">
     <option value="str0"> Строка списка 0 </option>
  </select>
```

на javascript отправляю запрос на сервер к адресу listlgotcat

```
function f(){
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET", "listlgotcat", true);
    x.send(null);
}
```

От сервера получаю ответ вида:

```
    farex@home:~$ curl -i localhost:3000/listlgotcat
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Sun, 05 Mar 2017 05:58:20 GMT
    Content-Length: 6
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

    a1
    a2
    a3
    farex@home:~$
```

как вывести этот запрос в

```
<option value="str0"> Строка списка 0 </option>
```

Список должен наполняться автоматически, из результата ответа на запрос к серверу.

В данном примере такого вида:

```
  <select id="mySelectId" name="mySelect">
     <option value="str0"> a1 </option>
     <option value="str1"> a2  </option>
     <option value="str2"> a3 </option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function f() {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.onload = function() {           

        // преобразование ответа сервера в массив
        var options = this.responseText.split('\n');
        var select = document.getElementById('mySelectId');

        // очистка списка
        while (select.options.length > 0) {
            select.options.remove(0);
        }        

        // заполнение списка
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = i;
            option.text = options[i];
            select.options.add(option);
        }            
    };
    x.open("GET", "/listlgotcat", true);
    x.send();
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое